# Is it possible to skip delegating a celery task if the params and the task name is already queued in the server?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Say that I have this task:

```
def do_stuff_for_some_time(some_id):
    e = Model.objects.get(id=some_id)
    e.domanystuff()
```

and I'm using it like so:

```
do_stuff_for_some_time.apply_async(args=[some_id], queue='some_queue')
```

The problem I'm facing is that there are a lot of repetitive tasks with the same arg param and it's boggling down the queue.

Is it possible to apply async only if the same args and the same task is not in the queue?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/sgrepo/celery-unique

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

Comment: @trinchet that wouldn't quite solve the issue of repeated tasks in the queue. You could still submit 100 of the same task with the same parameter but only one worker would ever be able to work on it, which still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[celery-singleton](https://github.com/steinitzu/celery-singleton) solves this requirement

Caveat: requires redis broker (for distributed locks)

`pip install celery-singleton`

Use the `Singleton` task base class:

```
from celery_singleton import Singleton

@celery_app.task(base=Singleton)
def do_stuff_for_some_time(some_id):
    e = Model.objects.get(id=some_id)
    e.domanystuff()
```

from the docs:

> calls to do_stuff.delay() will either queue a new task
>   or return an AsyncResult for the currently queued/running instance of
>   the task

Answer (score 3):

I would try a mix of a `cache lock` and a `task result backend` which stores each task's results:

- The cache lock will prevent tasks with the same arguments to get added to the queue multiple times. Celery documentation contains a nice example of cache lock implementation [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time), but if you don't want to create it yourself, you can use the [celery-once](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once) module.
- For a task result backend, we will use the recommended [django-celery-results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend), which creates a `TaskResult` table that we will query for task results.

**Example:**

- Install and configure [`django-celery-results`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend):

  `settings.py`:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      ...,
      'django_celery_results',
  )
  CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'  # You can also use 'django-cache'
  ```

  `./manage.py migrate django_celery_results`
- Install and configure the [`celery-once`](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once) module:

  `tasks.py`:

  ```
  from celery import Celery
  from celery_once import QueueOnce
  from time import sleep

  celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
  celery.conf.ONCE = {
      'backend': 'celery_once.backends.Redis',
      'settings': {
          'url': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
          'default_timeout': 60 * 60
       }
  }

  @celery.task(base=QueueOnce)
  def do_stuff_for_some_time(some_id):
      e = Model.objects.get(id=some_id)
      e.domanystuff()
  ```

  At this point, if a task with the same arguments is going to be executed,
  an `AlreadyQueued` exception will be raised.
- Let's use the above:

  ```
  from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult

  try:
      result = do_stuff_for_some_time(some_id)
  except AlreadyQueued:
      result = TaskResult.objects.get(task_args=some_id)
  ```

**Caveats:**

- Mind that at the time an `AlreadyQueued` exception arises, the initial task with argument=`some_id` may not be executed and therefore it will not have results in `TaskResult` table.
- Mind everything in your code that can go wrong and hang any of the above processes (because it will do that!).

**Extra Reading:**

- Another [Task with Lock DIY implementation](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3270#issuecomment-262761230)
- django-celery-result's [`TaskResult`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/master/django_celery_results/models.py#L17) model.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure if celery has such an option. However, I would like to suggest a work-around.

1) Create a model for all the celery tasks being queued. In that model, save the task_name, queue_name as well as the parameters

2) Use a get_or_create on that model for every celery task that is ready to be queued.

3) If created = True from step 2, allow the task to be added to the queue,  else do not add the task into the queue